# remove bootstrap navbar hover effect on button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, navbar

I want to remove the hover effect from my button in navbar how can i do that?[enter image description here][1]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar transparent">
  <div class="container-fluid logo ">
    <div class="navbar-header ">
      <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">
        <img src="images/Logo.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right right">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Get free trial</a>
      </li>
      <li class="Buybtn-topright">
        <a href="#">Buy now</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Which button are you talking about exactly and what is the hover effect? It would be very helpful if you could made a working fiddle with the code. Then we can give you a very definitive answer

Answer (score 5):

Add this css

```css
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: transparent !important;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <nav class="navbar navbar transparent">
      <div class="container-fluid logo ">
        <div class="navbar-header ">
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">
            <img src="images/Logo.png" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right right">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Get free trial</a>
          </li>
          <li class="Buybtn-topright">
            <a href="#">Buy now</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

`.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover, 
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,  {
       background-color: initial;
 }`

this would only remove the hover effect,not the active effect